# Issues with react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a value from one file to another.I am having issues with implementing context.Cant figure out what I am doing wrong here!

```js
import React from 'react'
const Mycontext = React.createContext();

class AppProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (< Mycontext.Provider value = {"Hello World"} > {this.props.children}</Mycontext.Provider>)}
     }
         
        export const ContextConsumer= Mycontext.Consumer;
```

I import the ContextConsumer to a file to render it.But I get a blank page,Is there something wrong with code??below is my react version.

> "react": "^16.4.2"

```js
import React from 'react'
import {ContextConsumer} from './contxt'


const Display=(props)=>{return(<p>{props.item}</p>)}


const ContextComponent=()=>{

 return(
    <ContextConsumer>
    {(data)=><Display item={data}/>}
    </ContextConsumer>
 )
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<ContextComponent/>, document.getElementById("index"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `AppProvider` at all. With this current setup probably you want something like that:

```js
const Mycontext = React.createContext();

class AppProvider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Mycontext.Provider value={"Hello World"}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Mycontext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const Display = (props) => { return (<p>{props.item}</p>) }

const ContextComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Mycontext.Consumer>
      {(data) => <Display item={data} />}
    </Mycontext.Consumer>
  )

}



ReactDOM.render(<AppProvider><ContextComponent /></AppProvider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```